# Android TextView text content set for a paragraph

Tags: android

i want to set some content on android text view.

Like...

"

> What is a Computer? A computer is a programmable machine. The two
>   principal characteristics of a computer are:
>
> 1. **It responds to a specific set of instructions in a well-defined manner.**
> 2. It can execute a *prerecorded* list of instructions (a program).

"

any one can help me

Tanks

Comment: Add the code that you tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtvew);
       tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>What is a Computer? A computer is a programmable machine. The two principal characteristics of a computer are:</p>" +
            "1. It responds to a specific set of instructions in a well-defined manner.<br/>" +
            "2. It can execute a prerecorded list of instructions (a program)."));
```

Comment: @faris: your problem solved or not if u have any issue then u can ask me any time. thanks!!!:-)